# Best way to close and reopen a Tkinter window

Tags: python, python-2.7, user-interface, tkinter

I have a program which looks like this:

```
def aStar(theMap, app):
    # Redraws the cell in the GUI
    def updateCell(x,y, value):
                theMap[y][x] = value
                app.gui.drawCell(x,y,value)

    # Do a lot of stuff which calls the method above

def solveScenario(scenario):
    class App(threading.Thread):
        def __init__(self, theMap, n, m, cellSize):
            self.root = Tk()
            self.root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.callback)

            self.gui = CellGrid(self.root,n,m,cellSize,theMap)
            self.gui.pack()

            threading.Thread.__init__(self)
            self.start()

        def callback(self):
            self.root.quit()

        def run(self):
            self.root.mainloop()

    prob = Problem(scenario)
    app = App(prob.theMap, prob.n, prob.m, 40)
    aStar()
    app.root.close()

def main():
    scenarios = # .. list of scenarios

    for i in scenarios:
        solveScenario(i)

class CellGrid(Canvas):
    theMap = None
    def __init__(self,master, rowNumber, columnNumber, cellSize, theMap):
        Canvas.__init__(self, master, width = cellSize * columnNumber , height = cellSize * rowNumber)
        self.cellSize = cellSize
        self.theMap = theMap
        #print theMap
        self.grid = []
        for row in range(rowNumber):
            line = []
            for column in range(columnNumber):
                line.append(Cell(self, column, row, cellSize, theMap[row][column]))
            self.grid.append(line)

        self.draw()

    def draw(self):
        for row in self.grid:
            for cell in row:
                cell.draw()

    def drawCell(self, x, y, value):
        cell = self.grid[y][x]
        cell.value = self.theMap[y][x]
        cell.draw()

class Cell():
    colors = {
            0: 'white',    # untried
            1: 'black',    # obstacle
            2: 'green',    # start
            3: 'red',      # finish
            4: 'blue',     # open
            5: 'gray',     # closed
            6: 'orange',   # path
         }

    def __init__(self, master, x, y, size, value):
        self.master = master
        self.abs = x
        self.ord = y
        self.size= size
        self.fill = "white"
        self.value = value

    def setValue(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def draw(self):
        """ order to the cell to draw its representation on the canvas """
        if self.master != None :
            xmin = self.abs * self.size
            xmax = xmin + self.size
            ymin = self.ord * self.size
            ymax = ymin + self.size

            self.master.create_rectangle(xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax, fill=self.colors[self.value], outline = "black")

main()
```

As you can see, for each scenario(problem), a matrix is drawn using Tkinter which is updated in real time by the A-Star algorithm. This works OK, but when switching from one scenario to another, the map changes. How can I refresh the Tkinter window? Using the code above, the cells stay colored when I generate a new map even though `app.root.close()` and `solveScenario()` is called again.

Thanks

Comment: Your title asks about closing and reopening a window, but the text of the question asks about refreshing a window. Is your real need simply that you need to delete the old results so you can start a new scenario?

Comment: Are you wanting to see multiple windows, each with a different scenario, all at the same time?